# Loop through ACF repeater rows in wordpress and display each row separately

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF repeater field called sub_seminars.
In some posts the repeater has multiple rows.
I want to loop through the rows and display each post separately based on the sub field "start_date"

I am doing something like this

```
<?php
                            $count = 0;
                                $your_repeater = get_field('sub_seminars');
                                if($your_repeater){
                                while( have_rows('sub_seminars') ): the_row();
                                $count++;
                                $my_field = get_sub_field('start_date');
                                if ($count == 1) { ?>



                                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                                                        <?php
                            // populate config with current post settings
                            presscore_populate_post_config();

                            presscore_get_template_part( 'theme', 'blog/list/blog-list-post' );
                            ?>

                               <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php } endwhile;  } ?>
```

But it works for the first post i.e count ==1 and fails when you increase the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
                $seminarid    = get_the_ID();
                $sub_seminars = get_field( 'sub_seminars', $seminarid );

               for ($nidu = 0; $nidu < count( $sub_seminars ); $nidu ++ ){

 ///////// Place your code here /////////////

} ?>
```

This is what will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($count == 1) {
```

to

```
if ($count > 1) {
```

It looks like you only run the loop to retrieve the fields if you are on the first iteration.

Comment: It loops and returns a lot of results. I tried this. Instead of returning 2 results it returns hundreds